# Se está arreglando / está siendo arreglado

Tags: gramática

¿Son estas frases intercambiables?

> My watch is still being fixed.

> 1. Mi reloj todavía se está arreglando.

> 2. Mi reloj todavía está siendo arreglado.

Comment: I will leave it to the experts to answer which is best but for some reason I would have started with todavia and then the verb and then mi reloj.

Comment: Sí, lo son. Pero, vas a oir la 1) muy frecuentemente. La 2) es más fácil para los que hablan inglés. Todavia **suele** ponerse donde está o al final de la frase. También se puede poner al principio, pero no lo haría yo así.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En general, la pasiva con "se" y la pasiva llamada perifrástica, formada por el verbo "ser" y el participio, son intercambiables, salvo que esté el agente (el que hace la acción), en cuyo caso solo puede usarse la segunda:

- Mi reloj todavía está siendo arreglado **por el relojero**.

Además, la pasiva con "se" en general se usa antes del sujeto, salvo que quiera enfatizarse:

- Se está construyendo el edificio.
- El edificio se está construyendo.
- El edificio está siendo construido.

En el caso del par de oraciones sobre las que se pregunta:

- Mi reloj todavía se está arreglando.
- Mi reloj todavía está siendo arreglado.

la primera oración suena muy rara, y creo que es porque el verbo "arreglarse" también puede ser un verbo pronominal que significa "mejorar":

- El tiempo se está arreglando (The weather is getting better)

Como hablante nativo, nunca diría: Mi reloj todavía se está arreglando, porque se superpone con el significado "mejorar". La perifrástica sería más correcta en este caso, o usaría un sujeto tácito "ellos" y diría:

- Mi reloj todavía lo están arreglando (They are still repairing my watch)

Comment: Qué sobre la frase _Mi reloj todavía se está reparando_?

Comment: Sí, con "reparar" suena mejor la pasiva con "se".